# Bash oneliner with pipes and if condition giving error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, pipe

I am trying to find the number of a particular process in bash using if condition as

```
if ps auwx | grep -v grep | grep -ic python -le 2; then echo error; else echo no_error; fi
```

and I am getting output as

```
grep: python: No such file or directory
```

no_error

The one-liner seems to break if I use pipe, and no error is thrown if I omit pipe, and it doesn't matter if I use the absolute path to grep either.I cannot get the required result without the pipe.  What am I doing wrong here? I can get this done in a script file, by breaking it into variables and then doing comparing it, but I was using this as an exercise to learn bash. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if `pgrep` is available on your machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, the syntax of `if` command is:

```
if cmd; then
    # cmd exited with status 0 (success)
else
    # cmd exited with status >0 (fail)
fi
```

The `cmd` above is the so-called *list* - a sequence of *pipelines*. Each pipeline is a sequence of commands separated with `|`.

The `-le` operator is interpreted **only** by the `test` command (also known as `[`, or `[[`), not by the `if` command.

So, when you say:

```
if ps auwx | grep -v grep | grep -ic python -le 2; then ... fi
```

you actually call `grep` with arguments:

```
grep -ic python -le 2
```

And since `-e` is used to specify the search pattern, the argument `python` is interpreted as a filename of the file to search for pattern `2`. That's why `grep` tells you it can't find file named `python`.

To test the output of a command pipeline in `if`, you can use the command substitution inside the `[[`/`[`/`test` (as the other answer suggests):

```
if [[ $(ps auwx | grep -v grep | grep -ic python) -le 2 ]]; then ... fi
```

or, within `(( .. ))`, with implicit arithmetic comparisons:

```
if (( $(ps auwx | grep -v grep | grep -ic python) <= 2 )); then ... fi
```

Comment: To extend this a bit: in bash scripting, context *matters*. Syntactic elements that mean one thing in a certain context (e.g. `-le` meaning less than or equal to inside `[ ]` or `[[ ]]`) usually mean something completely different in other contexts (e.g. following a `grep` command). The syntax rules in `[ ]` are slightly different from inside `[[ ]]`, which is totally different from inside `(( ))`, none of those have anything at all to do with what's valid inside `${ }`, and all of the above are different from what you can use just alone on a command line.

Answer (score 3):

using a command substitution in a condition

```
if [[ $(ps ...) -le 2 ]]; then
```

Comment: Thank you @nahuel-fouilleul, but it is giving me an error again. I re-wrote as per your answer to `if [[ $(ps auwx | /usr/bin/grep -v 'grep' | /usr/bin/grep -ic 'python') -le 2]]; then echo "error"; else echo "no_error"; fi` and it gives me  the following error `bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
bash: syntax error near `;'`

Comment: there should be a space `2 ]]`